# How do you setup firefox webdriver for selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to get a firefox webdriver (also attempted with chrome webdriver) to run with selenium. Every tutorial I look at does the same lines of code yet seems to run without issue. I have installed firefox thinking that might've been the problem but no luck. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. my code is written in winforms c# .net7 and runs on a button click. Any help with solving this is appreciated.

selenium packages installed via nuget:

[image: packages]

relevant code:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.Url = "https://www.youtube.com";
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    driver.Quit();
}
```

error (port changes each run):

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:65175/'
```

Comment: Have you made sure nothing else is running on port 65175? If you had previous instances of FirefoxDriver crash, then you might need to kill those instances before starting a new driver instance. Anti-virus and firewalls can also play havoc.

Comment: Which version of Firefox do you have?

Comment: I have firefox version 113.0.2 (64-bit) which is up to date as of yesterday which is when I downloaded it. Nothing is running on port 65175 as far as I'm aware (never port forwarded that specific port once in my life and I've ran this multiple times, each time it picks a new port randomly). I have checked to see if its stuck running in task manager after every run and didn't see it once running between runs. My IDE specifies the crash happens on this line: IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();